# zsh:1: parse error near `}' following the Jupiter IPython tutorial

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, zsh

I follow the Jupyter tutorial - **IPython - beyond plain python**, which can be redirected from [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/ipython/ipython-in-depth/master?filepath=binder/Index.ipynb3v/notebooks/examples/IPython%20Kernel/Beyond%20Plain%20Python.ipynb), got to the **Accessing the underlying operating system** section. Wrote the code below and got the error written in the title. That's the problem with `"{os.path.splitext(f)[0]}"`, how to fix it?

```
files = !ls
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    if f.endswith('ipynb'):
        !echo {"%02d" % i} - "{os.path.splitext(f)[0]}"
    else:
        print('--')
```

Comment: Your link does not work.

Comment: I  have fixed it.

Comment: First, you have to `import os`

Comment: @PouriaNikvand : Right, but this does not explain the **parse** error.

Comment: I added `import os`, restarted the jupyter server and the error disappeared. Didn't understand why it hasn't worked before.

Comment: @Intolighter From your link, I get "404 : Not Found
You are requesting a page that does not exist!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `import os` and restart the jupyter server.